# variance validation

Tags: statistics

The scores on a placement test given to college
freshmen for the past five years are approximately normally
distributed with a mean $μ = 74$ and a variance
$σ^2 = 8$. Would you still consider $σ^2 = 8$ to be a valid
value of the variance if a random sample of $20$ students
who take the placement test this year obtain a value of
$s^2 = 20$?

I think I'm supposed to use the F-distribution somehow in this problem, however, I've only been able to find out how to compare to sample variances--not how to compare a sample variance with a population variance. Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hypotheses:

$H_0: \sigma^2 = 8$

$H_1: \sigma^2 \neq 8$

This is a [$\chi^2$ test for one variance problem](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda358.htm).

*Assumptions* (taken from *Statistics Manual* by Crow, Davis, Maxfield):

1. The population has a normal distribution.
2. The sample is a random sample.

The test statistic under the null distribution is $$\chi^2 = \dfrac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2} = \dfrac{(20-1)(20)}{8} = 47.5\text{.}$$
I'm not sure what significance level you're using, but from here, it should be pretty straightforward.